# Removing tuples with duplicated first element from the list of tuples, summing their second elements

Tags: python, list, sorting, collections, tuples

So I got list like this

```
[('Add features to app', '5', '2022-10-28'), 
('Add features to app', '3', '2022-10-28'), 
('Deploy app to GitHub', '10', '2022-10-28'),
('Deploy app to GitHub', '2', '2022-10-28'),  
('Create an app, which gets tasks entries using API', '7', '2022-10-28')]
```

And I need to bring it to something like that:

```
[('Add features to app', '8', '2022-10-28'), 
('Deploy app to GitHub', '12', '2022-10-28'), 
('Create an app, which gets tasks entries using API', '7', '2022-10-28')]
```

This data is already grouped by date, so I have a collection of lists for each day and somehow need to sort it in the way I described before

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    ("Add features to app", "5", "2022-10-28"),
    ("Add features to app", "3", "2022-10-28"),
    ("Deploy app to GitHub", "10", "2022-10-28"),
    ("Deploy app to GitHub", "2", "2022-10-28"),
    ("Create an app, which gets tasks entries using API", "7", "2022-10-28"),
]

out = {}
for a, b, c in lst:
    out.setdefault((a, c), []).append(int(b))

out = [(a, str(sum(vals)), b) for (a, b), vals in out.items()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    ("Add features to app", "8", "2022-10-28"),
    ("Deploy app to GitHub", "12", "2022-10-28"),
    ("Create an app, which gets tasks entries using API", "7", "2022-10-28"),
]
```